# Auto run QA tools over jupyter notebook when saving

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, mypy, pylint

I want to run some tools like isort, black, pylint, pydocstyle etc. when I press ctrl+s on my jupyter notebook

I already have this independently as a terminal command using the `nbqa` library and will add a pre-commit hook, but I want it to feel more like an IDE while coding.

Is there any way to do this?